# SQL Server - INSERTED.OUTPUT - variable assign

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am doing the following:

```
UPDATE dbo.Crash
SET NbrOfCrash = NbrOfCrash + 1  
OUTPUT INSERTED.NbrOfCrash
WHERE CrashId = 1
```

Now I want to assign the OUTPUT of this statement into a variable :

```
DECLARE @result int;
```

This can be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1: you could use

```
UPDATE dbo.Crash
SET @result = NbrOfCrash = NbrOfCrash + 1  
WHERE CrashId = 1
```

only if there is a pk / unique key / unique constraint on CrashId column

or

option #2: otherwise, you may use

```
declare @updated_rows table (
NbrOfCrash int -- replace int with proper type
);

UPDATE dbo.Crash
SET NbrOfCrash = NbrOfCrash + 1  
OUTPUT INSERTED.NbrOfCrash into @updated_rows
WHERE CrashId = 1;

select @result = NbrOfCrash / min(NbrOfCrash) / max(NbrOfCrash) / avg(NbrOfCrash) ...
from @updated_rows;
```